# Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio 2.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I updated Android Studio to 2.1.3 and faced some problems which I got tired trying to solve them, I did researches on the internet and found solutions but they did not work .

1- When I open one of the previous projects which I made with the previous version it shows this message :

**Could not find method android() for arguments [build_271i3j5ikj90u04cm3b2z7cj$_run_closure2@769ff8fb] on root project 'MyApp' of type org.gradle.api.Project**

2- and under gradle root **I did not find "build.gradle(Module:app)" file .**

On other hand when I create a new project I have no problem and "build.gradle(Module:app)" file is exist and everything is OK .
[enter image description here][2]
any one help 
and thanks very much in advance .[Could not find method android() for arguments in Android Studio 2.1.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C15gY.png)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your project is wrong.

You should have:

```
root
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--module (ButtonAnimations)
|----build.gradle
```

Comment: How can I do to make the structure of my project correct ?

Comment: what is the reason "build.gradle(Module:app)"  is not exsist in the previous projects ?

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `gradle` folder and rebuild your project again.

Comment: Do you mean gradle folder which is in user folder ?  I have deleted it and run Android Studio again and let it download gradle stuff from the internet , but it does not work

Comment: One thing I forget to mention in my question that : when I open one of the old projects while the internet is connected it download gradle stuff for that project not for all projects , and it works good , which means it will download about 200 or 300 MB for each project  !!!

Comment: in that solution the code must be in "build.gradle(Module:app)" file which is not found in my situation , How can I do to get   "build.gradle(Module:app)" file

Comment: try to create another project and take that file from it and put it into your project Or move your Project Code to it.

Comment: if I download the latest version 2.2 does that gonna solve the problem ?